# 2011 Mini Cooper R56 Hardtop Sparkplug Gap

Tags: sparkplugs, mini-cooper

I would like to know whether I can use `NGK 90223` spark plugs on my 2011 Mini Cooper R56 hardtop with ~50k miles.

The original spark plugs on it (`Beru 12ZR6SP2`) seem to have worn and the engine is misfiring under load.

According to the Beru spec, they are supposed to have a spark gap of 1mm; the ones on my engine measure around 1.2-1.3mm though. `NGK 90223` has about a 0.8mm gap.

`NGK 90223` is recommended by many auto-stores as an OEM replacement. Since the spark gap is different, I am not sure whether I can replace `Beru 12ZR6SP2` with `NGK 90223`.

1. Can I replace `Beru 12ZR6SP2` with `NGK 90223`?
2. What is the Mini Cooper R56 recommended spark gap?

Comment: Which engine is in this Jean? Depending on whether this is the turbo version or not makes a difference. I'm not a Mini guy, so do not know what "R56" indicates specifically.

Comment: It appears the "R56" moniker just denotes the hardtop/hatch version. Just the plain Jane version, not the Countryman or whatever.

Comment: Mine is a Mini non-S hardtop version.

Comment: I have had four Mini's and found this site helpful  [MINI PARTS and SUPPORT](http://www.pelicanparts.com/catalog/SuperCat/6364_catalog.htm)  They have some good how tos

Answer (score 2):

[The Sparkplug.com reference site](http://www.sparkplug-crossreference.com/convert/beru/12ZR-6SP2) says there are only three sparkplugs which will work in place of the Beru 12ZR-6SP2:

```
BMW   12122158165
BMW   2158165
NGK   PLZKBR7A-G
```

Answer (score 2):

Not to confuse things but [Part Info](https://partinfo.org/beru-12zr6sp2/) lists the NKG 90223 (PLZKBR7B8DG) as an analogue plug to the Beru 12ZR6SP2.

As Paulster2 points out, the Rxx indicates the chassis information, not the engine.  I have a R55 (2012 Clubman) with the L4 1.6L N16B16A engine.  I called NKG and they confirmed that the 90223 is suitable for my engine.  They are pre-gapped at 0.032".  I am running with the NKG and am satisfied.

I compared NKG and Denso plugs and the consensus from several auto parts suppliers is that the NKG may provide slightly better fuel economy.  With the Beru plugs (At ~55K) I have been getting 32 mpg in mostly city driving (80/20), that with the 6-speed automatic.

If you want to verify your chassis/engine, [MiniMania](http://new.minimania.com/home.cfm) offers a nice vehicle finder tool, accessible on their home page.  Go the the 'My Account' dropdown and then to 'Your Car Type' and input the requested information and it will provide your chassis and engine number. You do not need to have or open and account to use the tool.

Hope that helps.